# chrome.storage.sync.set won't update the storage anymore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-storage

I am using chrome.storage.sync for some of my chrome extensions, great tool!

But I have an issue now, after updating the storage like 10 times. It blocks and does not update anymore... No error or anything so I do not know where the problem is.

FYI: I still have space in the storage.

The code:

```
Storage.get_all = function(callback) {
    STORAGE_SYNC.get('key', function(items) {
        callback(items.gifs_v2);
    });
};

Storage.post = function(id, item, callback) {
    var THIS = this;

    THIS.get_all(function(items) {
        if(items) {
            items[id] = item;
            STORAGE_SYNC.set({'key': items}, callback);
        } else {
            THIS.post_all({}, function() {
                THIS.post(id, item, callback);
            });
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: If you restart Chrome does it start working again? What about if you wait an hour and then try again? You might be running into rate limits.

Comment: Restarted chrome multiple times and waited couple of hours. I assumed that too, I though I reached a limit or something but still nothing.

Comment: Is [chrome.runtime.lastError](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError) set in the set or get callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several quotas published in the official documentation. Look it up. You probably run out of one of them. Remember that sync also goes into google's sync servers so abusing them will block you for a while. If you dont need to sync among devices use the regular local storage instead of sync.

Comment: I will try using local (king of brake the concept of my app but I do not really have a choice I guess). I Just don't understand that it does not raise any errors ...

Comment: it does raise errors, just not as exceptions. the call will fail and runtime.lastError will be set. see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#sync-properties

Comment: I did look at that, it was not set.

Comment: there are ways to get arround it if you really need sync. Keep the date of the last time you did a sync. If under 1 minute, store it in localStorage and remember that you need to call sync. have a timer that looks for things to sync every minute from localStorage into sync, little by little if you have many items.